Laravel application deployment and database connection issues on Railway app
I'm attempting to deploy my Laravel application on Railway app. I've set up the necessary information, but the database refuses to connect, producing the following error:

We are unable to connect to the database over the public network. Can
you connect using this command? 'mysql -hviaduct.proxy.rlwy.net -uroot
-p******** --port 19736 --protocol=TCP portfolio'.

When I try to run the command in the command prompt, it returns:

'mysql' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
program or batch file.

I've attempted to install MySQL, but the issue persists. Despite the inability to connect, I tried using the deployment URL in the front-end, which then threw this error:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for
viaduct.proxy.rlwy.net failed: No such host is known. (Connection:
mysql, SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE').

"viaduct.proxy.rlwy.net" is the host Railway generated for me, and I used it as demonstrated in the tutorial I was following. I expected it to connect and function correctly, but it failed.

As a quick test you could try replacing the domain with the IP which you can get by just pinging it.

Have you checked for firewall rules?
